# Is there an automatic way to migrate questions and answers and comments from one Team to another?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

My team at work started experimenting with Stack Overflow for Teams before the rest of the company followed. Now, we have two separate teams.

Is there an automatic way to migrate all the Q&A from one team to the other?